# How can I make the HTML form display fields based on specific condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an index page which has a form with different fields. I have built an entire utility with the following fields but now the requirements have changed. I want only the Controller Type and Test Type fields to display first and on submitting the data of these two fields I am using my config file to read and parse a YAML file in one of my local directories. Can anyone help me to modify the page, so that it accepts these two fields and then on submitting that the rest of the part of the form is displayed?

```js
document.getElementById("tab2").innerHTML = "<h4> Chassis 2 Details </h4>" + document.getElementById("extra").innerHTML;
```

```css
html,
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: teal;
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 19px;
}

html {
  background: #ABDCD6
}

input[type=button],
input[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text],
textarea,
select {
  font: 17px Calibri;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: teal;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

div {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

#tab1:hover,
#tab2:hover {
  background: #ABDCD6;
}

#tab1btn:hover,
#tab2btn:hover {
  background: #006899;
}

#tab1Content,
#tab2Content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.tab button {
  color: #1e84d8;
  /*margin-bottom: 0 px;*/
  background-color: #e7f6ff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.1s;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20a3eb;
}

#tab1btn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#tab1btn:focus {
  background-color: #f18973;
}

#tab2btn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#tab2btn:focus {
  background-color: #f18973;
}

#extra {
  display: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="C:\Users\735908\Desktop\Start\jsapp\node_modules\esprima/esprima.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\735908\Desktop\Start\jsapp\node_modules\js-yaml\dist/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
 <script src="testfile.js"></script>-->
<script src="testfile.js"></script>

<!-- insert templated additional details here -->

<form name='myForm'>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
    <select name='controller' id="Controller" required>
      <option value=""> - Select The Controller - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
        <option data-extra=true value='EBOD'>EBOD
          <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
    <select name='test' id="Test" required>
      <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
        <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
          <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
            <option data-extra=true value='Port Check'>Port Check
              <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic'>FW Generic
                <option data-extra=true value='EBOD Generic'>EBOD Generic
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Protocol Type'><strong> Protocol Type</strong></label>
    <select name='protocol' id="abc" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this);" required>
      <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS</option>
      <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI</option>
      <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
    <select id="tabsToDisplay" input type='text' name='chassis' required>
      <option value=""> - Number of Chasis - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
        <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Number of Controllers'><strong>Number of Controllers</strong></label>
    <select input type='text' name='ctrls' onchange="EnableDisableDropDown(this);" required>
      <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
        <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='IP Address'><strong> IP Address </strong></label>
    <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
  </fieldset>

  <div class="container">
    <label for='Left Outlets'><strong>Left Outlets </strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='lo' placeholder='Enter left outlets' required />
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for='Right Outlets'><strong>Right Outlets</strong></label>
    <input type='number' name='ro' placeholder='Enter right outlets' required />
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <button type="button" id="tab1btn" value="Chasis_1">Chasis 1</button>
    <button type="button" id="tab2btn" value="Chasis_2">Chasis 2</button>
  </div>

  <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
    <h4>Chasis 1 Details</h4>
    <div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">

      <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
      <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label><input type="text" class="CONTROLLER_ID" value="A" id='Controller_ID1' disabled="disabled" />
      <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
      <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
      <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' name='extra_ip1' id='mc_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
      <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
      <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
      <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' id='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' />
      <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' id='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' />
      <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' id='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' />
      <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' id='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' />
      <br>
      <br>
      <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
      <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label><input type="text" class="CONTROLLER_ID" value="B" id='Controller_ID' required />
      <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
      <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba1" placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
      <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' id='mcip' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
      <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
      <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
      <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" />
      <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" />
      <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" />
      <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
    <h4>Chasis 2 Details</h4>
    <div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">
    </div>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Download File' />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

added below jquery code. hope it helps you. Thanks

```
$('.btn-download').click(function() {
```

$('.extra-data').addClass('show')
})

```js
document.getElementById("tab2").innerHTML = "<h4> Chassis 2 Details </h4>" + document.getElementById("extra").innerHTML;

$('.btn-download').click(function() {
  $('.extra-data').addClass('show')
})
```

```css
html,
html * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color: teal;
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 19px;
}

html {
  background: #ABDCD6
}

input[type=button],
input[type=submit] {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-family: Times;
  font-size: 18px;
}

input[type=number] {
  width: 80%;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}

input[type=text],
textarea,
select {
  font: 17px Calibri;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: teal;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

div {
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}

#tab1:hover,
#tab2:hover {
  background: #ABDCD6;
}

#tab1btn:hover,
#tab2btn:hover {
  background: #006899;
}

#tab1Content,
#tab2Content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #B00098;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline;
}

.tab button {
  color: #1e84d8;
  /*margin-bottom: 0 px;*/
  background-color: #e7f6ff;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.1s;
  width: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20a3eb;
}

#tab1btn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#tab1btn:focus {
  background-color: #f18973;
}

#tab2btn {
  border: 1px solid rgb(19, 18, 18);
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: rgb(16, 8, 32);
  font-size: 25px;
  font-style: initial;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#tab2btn:focus {
  background-color: #f18973;
}

#extra {
  display: hidden;
}

.extra-data {
  display: none
}

.show {
  display: block !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="C:\Users\735908\Desktop\Start\jsapp\node_modules\esprima/esprima.js"></script>
    <script src="C:\Users\735908\Desktop\Start\jsapp\node_modules\js-yaml\dist/js-yaml.min.js"></script>
 <script src="testfile.js"></script>-->
<script src="testfile.js"></script>

<!-- insert templated additional details here -->

<form name='myForm'>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Controller Type'><strong>Controller Type </strong></label>
    <select name='controller' id="Controller" required>
      <option value=""> - Select The Controller - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='RAID'>RAID
        <option data-extra=true value='EBOD'>EBOD
          <option data-extra=true value='AP'>AP
    </select>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <label for='Test Type'><strong>Test Type</strong></label>
    <select name='test' id="Test" required>
      <option value=""> - Select The Test - </option>
      <option data-extra=true value='BFT'>BFT
        <option data-extra=true value='CTO'>CTO
          <option data-extra=true value='RAID Generic'>RAID Generic
            <option data-extra=true value='Port Check'>Port Check
              <option data-extra=true value='FW Generic'>FW Generic
                <option data-extra=true value='EBOD Generic'>EBOD Generic
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="extra-data">
    <fieldset>
      <label for='Protocol Type'><strong> Protocol Type</strong></label>
      <select name='protocol' id="abc" onchange="EnableDisableTextBox(this);" required>
        <option value=""> - Select The Protocol - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='SAS'>SAS</option>
        <option data-extra=true value='iSCSI'>iSCSI</option>
        <option data-extra=true value='FC'>FC</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Chasis Input'><strong>Number of Chasis</strong></label>
      <select id="tabsToDisplay" input type='text' name='chassis' required>
        <option value=""> - Number of Chasis - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
          <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='Number of Controllers'><strong>Number of Controllers</strong></label>
      <select input type='text' name='ctrls' onchange="EnableDisableDropDown(this);" required>
        <option value=""> - Number of Controllers - </option>
        <option data-extra=true value='1'>1
          <option data-extra=true value='2'>2
      </select>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <label for='IP Address'><strong> IP Address </strong></label>
      <input type='text' name='ip' placeholder='Enter your IP address' required />
    </fieldset>

    <div class="container">
      <label for='Left Outlets'><strong>Left Outlets </strong></label>
      <input type='number' name='lo' placeholder='Enter left outlets' required />
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label for='Right Outlets'><strong>Right Outlets</strong></label>
      <input type='number' name='ro' placeholder='Enter right outlets' required />
    </div>

    <div class="tab">
      <button type="button" id="tab1btn" value="Chasis_1">Chasis 1</button>
      <button type="button" id="tab2btn" value="Chasis_2">Chasis 2</button>
    </div>

    <div id="tab1" class="tabcontent">
      <h4>Chasis 1 Details</h4>
      <div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">

        <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller A</h6>
        <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label><input type="text" class="CONTROLLER_ID" value="A" id='Controller_ID1' disabled="disabled" />
        <label for='iSCSI1'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip1' id="ip1" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
        <label for='HBA_Ports_A'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba" name='hba_ports1' placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
        <label for='MC_IP_A'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' name='extra_ip1' id='mc_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
        <label for='MC_Netmask_A'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id='netmask_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
        <label for='MC_Gateway_A'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id='gateway_ip1' placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
        <label for='MC_A'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' id='rbod_mc1' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' />
        <label for='SC_A'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' id='rbod_sc1' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' />
        <label for='FU_A'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' id='rbod_fu1' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' />
        <label for='EC_A'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' id='rbod_ec1' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' />
        <br>
        <br>
        <h6>Additional Details Required for Controller B</h6>
        <label for='Controller_ID1'>Controller_ID:</label><input type="text" class="CONTROLLER_ID" value="B" id='Controller_ID' required />
        <label for='iSCSI2'>iSCSI IPs:</label><input class="iSCSI_IP" type='text' name='iSCSIip2' id="ip2" placeholder='Enter iSCSI ips' disabled="disabled" />
        <label for='HBA_Ports'>HBA_Ports:</label><input class="hba_ports" type='text' id="hba1" placeholder='Enter the HBA Ports' disabled="disabled" />
        <label for='MC_IP'>MC_IP:</label><input class="mc_ip" type='text' id='mcip' name='extra_ip' placeholder='Enter the MC_IP' />
        <label for='MC_Netmask'>MC_Netmask:</label><input class="Netmask_IP" type='text' id="netmaskip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Netmask' />
        <label for='MC_Gateway'>MC_Gateway:</label><input class="Gateway_IP" type='text' id="gatewayip" placeholder='Enter the MC_Gateway' />
        <label for='MC'>MC:</label><input class="RBOD_MC" type='text' name='rbod_mc' placeholder='Enter the MC Port' id="rbodmc" />
        <label for='SC'>SC:</label><input class="RBOD_SC" type='text' name='rbod_sc' placeholder='Enter the SC Port' id="rbodsc" />
        <label for='FU'>FU:</label><input class="RBOD_FU" type='text' name='rbod_fu' placeholder='Enter the FU Port' id="rbodfu" />
        <label for='EC'>EC:</label><input class="RBOD_EC" type='text' name='rbod_ec' placeholder='Enter the EC Port' id="rbodec" />

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tabcontent">
      <h4>Chasis 2 Details</h4>
      <div id="extra" style="display:hidden;">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset>
    <input type='submit' name='save' value='Download File' class="btn-download" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```